# Echo some data not just inside php tag

Tags: php, html, dom

I have to files. On file, let say go.php has this source code:

```
<?php include('folder1/folder2/main.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>   
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 data-loop="true">This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<span data-loop="true"> tag span</span>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p data-loop="true">This is loop</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The second file main.php has this inside:

```
<?php

if(file_get_contents(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) === false) {

} else {


$document = file_get_contents(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));

ltrim( $document, '<?php' );
rtrim( $document, '?>' );
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($document);
$root = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
$tag = $doc->getElementsByTagName('*');


for($b=0; $tag->length > $b; $b++) {
    if( ($tag->item($b) == true) and ($tag->item($b)->hasAttribute('data-loop')) ) {
        $tag->item($b)->removeAttribute('data-loop');
        $cloned = $tag->item($b)->cloneNode(true);
        $root->insertBefore($cloned, $tag->item($b));
    }
    if($tag->length - 1 == $b) {

    }   

}

echo $doc->saveHTML();

}

?>
```

The second file loops through the file go.php, add some tags and gives results. But thing is that as a result I have the original source code of go.php and the new one. I would like to have only new source code, but I don't what to erase the old source code from go.php. So `file_put_contents()` isn't an option. It would be great to just echo new source code through all go.php.

Comment: Would output buffer do the trick? Ideally, only one file would be nice. I would like to escape creating a new one with old source code etc.

Comment: Use session_start() at the top of your code and store the output in a session variable, view-able on another page (after refresh)